# Distinguish javascript of Console & Browser

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools

Is there a way to distinguish javascript code that belongs to a website and javascript code that is run from the Console tab in Chrome DevTools?

What I'm trying to do is the following:

Initialize a `DEBUG` variable to `true` when I copy paste my javascript code to the Console and `false` when the javascript code is either located in a `<script>` tag inside the html file or downloaded from the browser as in an external `.js` file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The console has a few global functions. You can do:

```
var DEBUG = typeof clear === 'function'; // clear() is a global in the console to clear the screen
```

Just make sure you don't define a global variable `clear`.